# Build Model In Dart For This Form Of Json

Tags: json, flutter, dart, model

how I can parse this form of json ?
Where "Question" is an object and not an array, the number of elements within it is not fixed but is related to the length of "question_ids" and the key of each object within it is taken from "question_ids"

```
{
"questions": {
                "96292": {
                    "correct": false,
                    "mark": 0,
                    "answered": ""
                },
                "96293": {
                    "correct": false,
                    "mark": 0,
                    "answered": ""
                },
                "96294": {
                    "correct": false,
                    "mark": 0,
                    "answered": ""
                }
            },
"question_ids": [
            96292,
            96293,
            96294
           
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just copy and paste your json model to https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/ this will auto generate your model

Answer (score 0):

if you want the id to be in the result use

```
  final jsonMap = jsonDecode(valueFromApi);
  final questions = (jsonMap['questions'] as Map<String, Map>?)
      ?.entries
      .map<Map>((item) => {"id": item.key, ...item.value});
```

if you don't need the id use

```
  final jsonMap = jsonDecode(valueFromApi);
  final questions = (jsonMap['questions'] as Map<String, Map>?)
      ?.entries
      .map<Map>((item) => item.value);
```

you should also have a `Question` class has all the attribute you need

and use this line to convert your data to object

```
 final entity = questions?.map((e) => Question.fromJson(e)).toList();
```